# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\EventsController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, routes

theres a create button on my admin page where its supposed to open the create page

```
<a href="{{route('create')}}">Add Event</a>
```

My controller function to create open this is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Event;

class EventsContoller extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('layouts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

My `web.php` route is

```
Route::get('/admin/create', 'EventsController@create')->name('create');
```

i've tried **composer dumpautoload** but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your controller seems incomplete.. how did you generate it? Did you use `php artisan make:controller EventsController`?

The file should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Event;

class EventsController extends Controller 
{

    public function create()
    {
        return view('layouts.create');
    }

}
```

Comment: @mimikiduchu then why did you shared a different code above?

Comment: @mimikiduchu no you were not, please copy paste the full class above. You are missing `{` now.

Comment: @mimikiduchu Your class is called `EventsContoller` it should be `EventsController`.